# Is the mqm group and user for Websphere/IM MQ 9.0 hard-coded?

Tags: ibm-mq

One of the tasks needed to be performed before [installing IBM MQ 9.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q128440_.htm) on linux is given as:

> Set up a **user ID of the name mqm, with a primary group of mqm**. See
>   Setting up the user and group on Linux.

Further details about having mqm user and mqm group are given [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008503_.htm):

IBM documentation says that a user must be part of mqm group to run administration commands like crtmqm (create queue manager) or strmqm (start queue manager).

I would like to use a different group name. Where can I configure the name of the group mqm? Or is this hard-coded?

Comment: It is hard closed.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks does IBM mention anywhere in documentation? Any workaround to change it..

Comment: Only on windows as far as I know at this time.

Comment: Rare, what is the reason to not use mqm?

Comment: @JoshMc in our organization network, there is a group with name mqm.. So unable to create group with same name at /etc/group

Comment: Is these mqm group available to the linux server? It bred not be a local group.

Comment: Yes, it is available..but when I try to add user to mqm group.. it gives error.. 'group mqm doesn't exist at /etc/group' @JoshMc

Comment: What command are you using to add the user?  How is the group made available to the server?  If via LDAP or similar, is it possible the mqm user already exists?  The user also need not be local.

Comment: gpasswd -a user mqm.  I am not sure how mqm group is available to the server. User mqm got created with IBM MQ installation in my linux server. Though 'groups mqm' mentions that it has primary group as mqm. When I use 'getent group mqm', the user is not listed. @JoshMc

Comment: Primary group is just a field in the passwd entry that references the numeric GID of the group.   The user can also be a regular member of the group in the group entry but it is not required.  Does `getent passwd mqm` have more than one entry?  It sounds like you should be fine.

Comment: @JoshMc getent passwd mqm has only one entry.it references gid of mqm group. .do you say that  after 'su mqm', I should be able to run administrative commands?

Comment: Yes you should.  MQ only cares about the name and that you are a member.

Comment: @JoshMc I installed MQ and created a new queue manager and also a local queue, disabled channel auth and ConnAUTH. in WAS 9.0, I am creating Connection Factory Resources > JMS providers > WebSphere MQ messaging provider > Connection factories When I try to connect to MQ, Test Connection fails..reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED'). Any thoughts?

Comment: That is a different issue.   Check this search for that error,  if you can't resolve please post a new question.  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22reason%20%272035%27%20(%27MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED%27)%22

Comment: I'll write up a answer to this question with what we already discussed in the comments.